# SQL syntax error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm inserting value to my MySQL table from `php` as:

```
$journey = $_POST['way'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$dpdt = $_POST['dp_date'];
$rtdt = $_POST['rt_date'];
$fare = $_POST['fare'];
$sql = "insert into tours set " .
        "journey='$journey', from='$from', to='$to', dp_date=CAST('$dpdt' AS DATE), " .
        "rt_date=CAST('$rtdt' AS DATE), fare='$fare'";
```

on trying `echo` for `$sql` I'm getting output as:

```
insert into tours set journey='round', from='Aurangabad', to='Kashmir', dp_date=CAST('27-08-2013' AS DATE), rt_date=CAST('21-08-2013' AS DATE), fare='2500'
```

but I'm continuously getting the same error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from=Aurangabad, to='Kashmir', dp_date=CAST('27-08-2013' AS DATE), rt_date=CAST(' at line 1
```

even if I try to remove `'` around the values of column names.
I'm using the same syntax for inserting data and that's working fine.
 What's wrong with this?
Why MySQL does not give a proper error for such terrible mistake?

Comment: `FROM` is a reserved word in SQL; you need to either escape it with backticks, or use a fieldname that isn't a reserved word - the latter solution will give you fewer headaches.

Comment: You should also watch out for sql injections

Comment: oh my gosh! what a terrible mistake. I've used `from` as column name

Comment: mysql must state properly for such error

Comment: Why people voting down this question? Can't they just ask this to be closed or deleted?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Because you are working extremely messy I think.

Comment: @Nils: How could I prevent SQL injection?

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string/mysqli_real_escape_string/PDO::quote depending on the API you're using. Note that PDO::quote adds single quote but the other two functions doesn't so you need to add it afterwords. I would also recommend that you use **bindings**, both PDO and mysqli has it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
`from`='$from', `to`='$to'
```

`FROM` is reserved word use backtick around it.

Answer (score 3):

`FROM` is reserved keyword and you should not use it. [Refer Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 2):

'from' and 'to' are reserve words

Try to do like this

```
[from] = 'Aurangabad', [to] ='Kashmir'
```

Answer (score 2):

`FROM` is a SQL-Keyword. You must not use that without delimiters as a column name.